# Difficulty setting up internet sharing on Beaglebone on macOS Big Sur

Tags: linux, networking, macos, embedded-linux, beaglebone

I am having trouble setting up an internet to be shared on Beaglebone (BB) through the host (Mac running Big Sur OS).

When I do `ifconfig` on BB, I see two USB interfaces showing up (usb0, usb1) with a designated IP addresses but I can't seem to ping to my host machine for instance. It says `From 192.168.7.2 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable`

According to this [link](https://beagleboard.org/latest-images):

> With the latest images, it should no longer be necessary to install drivers for your operating system to give you network-over-USB access to your Beagle. In case you are running an older image, an older operating system or need additional drivers for serial access to older boards, links to the old drivers are below.

```
usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.7.2  netmask 255.255.255.252  broadcast 192.168.7.3
        inet6 fe80::e1c:57ff:fe00:c2c0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0c:1c:57:00:c2:c0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.6.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.6.255
        ether 0c:1c:57:00:c2:c4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I did download the latest image but for further verification, how do you verify the image being run i.e version or something that tells whether this matches the image version 10.3 as stated on the website?

**Edit:**

- On the host, following is the relevant interface for the USB. For the pings to go through, the netmask needs to be matched with that of the `usb0`?

```
en7: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=404<VLAN_MTU,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 0c:1c:57:00:c2:c3 
    inet6 fe80::d1:b3cb:50eb:72e1%en7 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x14 
    inet 192.168.7.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.6.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (none)
    status: inactive
```

- In the [Network Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soifD.png) of the host, I see it says `Either the cable for BeagleBoneBlack is not plugged in or the device at the other end is not responding.` That's weird because in the `ifconfig` output on the host, I do see `en7` showing up which is referring to the USB connection to the BeagleBone
- the output of `ip addr` on beaglebone is as follows - not quite sure why usb1 has no carrier and whether it relates to [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soifD.png)

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:1c:57:00:c2:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:1c:57:00:c2:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.7.2/30 brd 192.168.7.3 scope global usb0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e1c:57ff:fe00:c2c0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: usb1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:1c:57:00:c2:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.6.2/24 brd 192.168.6.255 scope global usb1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 0):

ifconfig's up means that the interface is logically on. It doesn't say, it has got a link neither that the connection is working well.

"Check the cable first" is a golden rule. Maybe the cable is wrong, maybe interfaces are not MDI/MDI-X capable and the cable is not cross-wired. A connection with an ethernet switch or to a different device might help.

You can test the lower level with `arp -an` (on Mac) or `ip nei` on GNU/Linux. You should see the other computer filled-in in the arp table after the ping try.

Then I would check again settings.

The important thing to mention is: we are trying to establish a connection between the Mac and the Beaglebone box (addresses 192.168.7.1 and 192.168.7.2). It doesn't mean, you can go further to "the other end" of Beaglobone. There would need to be forwarding switch set in the kernel of Linux (`sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`) and or an iptables rule for NAT or a proper routing table set at all computers involved.

BTW: the mask doesn't really need to be the same, it influences only the decision whether the packet shell be directed/routed according to a routing table or given to a lower-level protocol of LAN. But it's not really convenient to live in a great mass, isn't it? But the broadcat is really wrong and can't work.

Comment: how else would you determine if the link is working well? I used `ip addr` and it says `usb1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>` but things look OK for `usb0`. `arp -an` on Mac doesn't return the IP address of the `usb0` of the beagle but I do see the host interface's IP on beagle

Comment: `inet 192.168.7.2  netmask 255.255.255.252 ` means pings could be only sent to addresses between `192.168.7.1` and `192.168.7.2`, no?

Comment: Well, "NO-CARRIER" is expressive. It means there is no connection on a link level. Check the cable -- see above :-) In those old times there were those little LED lights on adapters and switches. They were a bit optimistic (half of the connection were enough to light up) but, helpful...

Comment: Yes, mask ...252 aka network /30 is only for 2 computers (four address network, but the first is the address of the network itself, the last is the broadcast - all computers in the network).

Comment: which cable are you referring to? the USB-TTL or the one that's powering beaglebone?

Comment: You are right, I am silly, there shouldn't be any connection issues with a proper USB cable. The ethernet is just emulated by rndis. I am sorry, I have no proper HW to replicate the problem at the moment.

Comment: so maybe your answer to this post isn't an answer...

Comment: Well, that's may be a bit too harsh. I am just trying to help. Well, what about editing your original post to contain the important parts - e.g. NO-CARRIER. I may higher your chance to get a better answer significantly :-)

Comment: no no I meant in the sense that the answer on SO is considered an answer if it actually solved a problen. Not that you didn't put in an effort :)